# Impossible to resolve unmet dependences while installing cocos2d-x

Tags: software-installation, dependencies, compiling, cmake

I'm trying to install cocos2d-x in an Ubuntu 14.04.2 but when I try to compile it with cmake it gives me this error:

```
CMake Error at cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:136 (message): Could NOT find CURL (missing: CURL_LIBRARY CURL_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

I run

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

But it gives me an error of unmet dependences:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas: libcurl4-openssl-dev : Depende: librtmp-dev pero no va a instalarse E: No se pudieron corregir los problemas, usted ha retenido paquetes rotos.
```

I've already tried:

```
apt-get clean apt-get autoclean apt-get autoremove apt-get install -f ...
```

I've also tried to follow the dependency chain:

```
$ sudo apt-get install librtmp-dev
Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas: librtmp-dev : Depende: libgnutls-dev pero no va a instalarse
```

And:

```
$ sudo apt-get install librtmp-dev
Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas: libgnutls-dev : Depende: libgnutls-openssl27 (= 2.12.23-12ubuntu2.1) pero 3.2.16-1u1~ppa2 va a ser instalado
```

And finally:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libgnutls-openssl27
libgnutls-openssl27 ya está en su versión más reciente. 0 actualizados, 0 se instalarán, 0 para eliminar y 0 no actualizados.
```

(already installed)

What's going on and/or how can I solve it?

Comment: Can you try the following: `sudo apt-get install librtmp-dev libgnutls-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev` and see if it works?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I solved it with:

```
sudo apt-get remove libgnutls-openssl27
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```